# Finding an isometry that maps one circle to another.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

I have a problem goes as follows:

Consider the unit speed curve $$\boldsymbol{r}(s)=\left(\frac{4}{5}\cos(s),1-\sin(s),-\frac{3}{5}\cos(s)\right).$$

Find an isometry $f$ such that $f(\boldsymbol{r}(s))$ is the circle $$(\cos(s),\sin(s),0).$$

---

I am not sure how to approach this problem. I understand that I have to find a function (more specifically an isometry) that maps each ordinate to another, but I do not know how to find it. Nor do I know any methodical approach to help me.

Thank you to all in advanced for your help.

Comment: You might like to start by finding the normal to the plane that the circle lies in. Then recall that (orientation preserving) isometries of $\mathbb{R}^3$ are compositions of translations and rotations about the origin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first parametrization can be written

\begin{align}
   \boldsymbol{r}(s) &= \cos(s)\,\langle 4/5,0,-3/5 \rangle +\sin(s)\,\langle 0,-1,0 \rangle +\langle 0,1,0 \rangle \\
 &= \cos(s)\,\boldsymbol{u} + \sin(s)\,\boldsymbol{v} +\boldsymbol{p}
\end{align}

Note that $\boldsymbol{u}$ and $\boldsymbol{v}$ are already orthogonal with unit length so
you simply need to shift back by $\boldsymbol{p}$ and then find a linear transformation mapping $\boldsymbol{u}$ and $\boldsymbol{v}$ to $\boldsymbol{i}$ and $\boldsymbol{j}$ respectively.

Comment: Wow, that was a very nice observation! Thank you. I will work on it from here.

Comment: @GustavoMontano Cool! I was hoping that would help.